# docker-compose Error... [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.36-1debian10 started

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db_data1:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USER}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    command:
      - --character-set-server=utf8mb4
      - --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

  web:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./web_data1:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      DJANGO_DB_HOST: db:3306
      DJANGO_DB_NAME: "${DB_DATABASE}"
      DJANGO_DB_USER: "${DB_USER}"
      DJANGO_DB_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
```

### my_setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}",
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

SECRET = 'django-insecure-#kb%p45em8hdhja^+2jal#(*mzw1c3jk5gvsx(_cn@q^u@u&b0'

ALGORITHM = 'HS256'
```

### Dockerfile

FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "docker_train.wsgi:application"]

### .env

```
DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USER=root
```

I run docker-compose up but got this error.
How can I approach it to solve the problem?

### error

```
docker-training11-db-1   | 2021-11-09 05:14:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.36-1debian10 started.
docker-training11-web-1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
docker-training11-web-1  | Performing system checks...
```

Comment: What you have posted is no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am able to identify, you are facing some issue with your DATABASE details. Kindly verify them first.

django is not able to resolve db host name.
instead of 'db' try passing private ip of base machine.